# Withdrawal function in eth decimals

Tags: solidity, remix

```
function depositETHforXYZ() public payable freezeFunction returns(bool success) {
        require(msg.value > 0 ether, "Cannot be 0");
        require(msg.sender.balance > 0 ether, "Not enough funds");
 
        totalSupply = totalSupply.add((msg.value.mul(conversionRate)).div(1000000000000000000));
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].add((msg.value.mul(conversionRate)).div(1000000000000000000));

        emit Swap(msg.sender, "ETH", msg.value, "XYZ", msg.value.mul(conversionRate));
        emit TokensMinted(msg.value.mul(conversionRate));
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);

        return true;
    }

    function withdrawXYZforETH(uint _xyzAmount) public freezeFunction returns(bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] != 0, "No funds to withdraw");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _xyzAmount, "Not enough funds to withdraw");
        
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_xyzAmount);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_xyzAmount);
        // doesn't withdraw the correct amount below 1 eth (decimals dont work)
        msg.sender.transfer((_xyzAmount.div(conversionRate)).mul(1000000000000000000));
        
        emit Swap(msg.sender, "XYZ", _xyzAmount, "ETH", _xyzAmount.div(conversionRate));
        emit TokensBurned(_xyzAmount);
        emit Withdrawal(msg.sender, (_xyzAmount.div(conversionRate)));
        
        return true;
    }
```

100 xyz = 1 eth. I calculate the xyzAmount(100)/conversionRate(100) = 1. If I don't use the 18 digits it will send 1 wei. My problem is that it wont send the correct amount of wei when less than 1 eth worth of wei.

Not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "withdraw ether in decimals".

Comment: So if I converted my token to eth and withdrew that amount so say 0.5eth, how would I do that?

Comment: And how much does the contract function give you?

Comment: BTW, get rid of that `1000000000000000000` everywhere in your contract. All calculations are done in wei, and the contract should own no knowledge of the 18 decimals that this number represents. More generally, decimals are designated to be used off-chain only (e.g., apps, websites, etc), in order to display human-readable numbers.

Comment: It won't end up sending the right amount if you introduce those "18 decimals" into your contract's code. ETH is denoted in **wei resolution** cross-blockchain!

Comment: Why did you just dump your entire code in here, with no question being asked? This post will be closed. Please post ONLY the relevant information, and add one specifically related question.

Comment: I edited the code so you can see the whole thing and test in remix. If I don't use the 18 decimals, it wont send the correct amount of eth - try it and see. I'm just saying, it messes up the calculations when sending 0.1-0.99 eth

Comment: "If I don't use the 18 decimals" - then what's the `1000000000000000000` for???

Comment: To convert it to eth. 100 xyz = 1 eth. I calculate the xyz/conversionRate(100) = 1. If I don't use the 18 digits it will send 1 wei. My problem is that I wont send the correct amount of less than 1 eth worth of wei.

Comment: See my answer below...

Comment: And the example that I have added below it as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every function in your contract which is called from the off-chain (e.g., a web3.js script):

- For every token-amount that the function receives as input, you should take that input from the user and convert it to decimal resolution before you pass it to the function
- For every token-amount that the function returns as output, you should take that output from the function and convert it to token resolution before you pass it to the user

The contract function does not need to know anything about the token `decimals` value.

I hope that this description clarifies things for you...

Comment: For example, suppose your token has 5 decimals. If you need to pass 42 tokens from the user to a contract function, then you pass `4200000`. If a contract function returns `123456789`, then you need to inform the user of `1234.56789` tokens.

Comment: The contract function should make no use of `100000` in that sense. Neither as a multiplier, nor as a divider.

Comment: I ended up changing the format to ``` _xyzAmount = _xyzAmount.mul(1000000000000000000);
        msg.sender.transfer(_xyzAmount.div(conversionRate)); ``` after reading your post, it now works :) Thank you for that